# What file format contents starts with "URES"?

Tags: file, embedded-resource, file-type

I have a number of files that contain data in a format I am not familiar with.  All of the data files begin with the same byte sequence, presumably a file header, and the sequence is "URES".  I'm assuming that these files are some kind of resource file, perhaps a collection of data or other files all embedded into one file; that's just a guess however.

Does anyone know what format this is/might be?

If so, how would I interrogate the file?  Are there applications that let me open these kind of files?  Do you know of any libraries or APIs that I can use to gain programmatic access the data?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the unix `file` command on it?

Comment: I'm using Windows, so no, I have not run the 'file' command.  What would that have done for me?

Comment: This command is used for identifying files. It has a huge database of signatures and magic bytes, so chances were that it knew about your file.

Comment: I ran "file" on one of the URES files and it doesn't know what it is.  It calls it "Data" `$ file /Volumes/WTLIB11E/rs_data/PUBS/FY_E/FY_E.PUB 
/Volumes/WTLIB11E/rs_data/PUBS/FY_E/FY_E.PUB: data`

Answer (score 1):

I know of one file format that starts with URES. It's a data file used for Watchtower Library. I have yet to understand the format myself.

Answer (score 0):

maybe its something from the Universal Resource Editor (URE) that comes with the OS/2 Toolkit? just a guess...

Answer (score 0):

it is from the watchtower library files and they use meps to encode it which is thier own librarys and encryption software so to crack it would take you a long time.